# Certificate can only be used by network service account, cannot be used by domain account

Tags: wcf, security, ssl, https, certificate

Issues :

Our service is using one certification for partner service call. It worked all well in IIS site which is running as network service account. But when we run test the code as administrator (domain account), the service call will always get 403 error (sub status code is 7: certificate is required).

We have verify:

- Attach debugger to the process we found the site can access to private key when running as domain account.
- The cert is in domain account's CURRENT_USER/MY cert store. And the cert authorization chain is good in cert store. The special thing of this cert is its root CA is an corporate internal CA. But the CA is already in the trust root.
- In IE, if we directly visit one https site, this cert is not in the pop-up list. But it do exist in the IE Options-Content-certificates-personal list. (Not sure if this related)

Questions:

Seems the certificate usage is blocked by some security settings (windows or some corporate domain policy), how to troubleshot the issue ? Any thoughts is welcomed. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Command `certutil -store my` will try to use all certificates in local machine\my store. It will list information about certificates that were tested.

Optionally, command `certutil -user -store my` will test certificates in current user\my store.

Try both commands and see in what store the certificate and its corresponding private key is stored.
For more information about certutil see documentation [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc732443.aspx).